# Одна страница всего сайта выдаёт ошибку 500

Tags: php

вопрос такой. Из всех страниц сайта, только одна выдаёт ошибку

> Страница недоступна Сайт domain.net пока не может обработать этот запрос.
> HTTP ERROR 500

Пользователь получает письмо с ссылкой, по которой должен пройти. И происходит ошибка. На локальном хостинге работает, на обычном хостинге нет. Прочитав много ресурсов с описание ошибки, увеличение *memory* не помогло. Подскажите куда двигаться в поиске ответа?

Код:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT code FROM users WHERE ID = :id');
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
    header ('Location: error404.html');
    exit;
}

while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $_SESSION['code'] = $result->code;
}

if($_SESSION['code'] == $_GET['code']){
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE users SET `Activation` = 1 WHERE users.ID = :id');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}else{
    header('Location: error404.html');
}
```

Comment: В сторону обработки ответов функций, логирования, отладки, и просмотра логов сервера.

Comment: начните с конца сообщения выше и просмотрите логи сервера

Comment: код-то не целиком у вас тут приведен,  или как оно без `session_start` у вас работает?

Comment: @teran он есть. Я просто не полный код ввёл. Без всяких подключений к БД и начало сессий.